# Issues Persisting Data in Keycloak with PostgreSQL on Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

**Description:**
I am facing difficulties persisting data in a Keycloak deployment running on Kubernetes and connected to a PostgreSQL database. When I stop the Keycloak pod, I lose data, and I suspect it's not correctly connected to the database.

**Details:**

My keycloak-deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6
          args: ["start"]
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: xxxx
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: xxxx
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "edge"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_DB_VENDOR
              value: POSTGRES
            - name: DB_ADDR
              value: postgres-service
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              value: xxxx
            - name: DB_USER
              value: xxxx
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: xxxx
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              value: env-xxxxxxx.jcloud.ik-server.com
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
```

and my postgres-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:13.1
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: keycloak
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: keycloak
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: your_password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

I have not set up Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs) for Keycloak and PostgreSQL for the moment, but it should not change anything since I have not stopped the postgresql pod.

**Expected Outcome:**
I want Keycloak to persist data in the connected PostgreSQL database, even when the Keycloak pod is stopped and restarted.

**Any help or suggestions are appreciated! Thank you.**

Comment: Turn up logging on both pods and look in the logs.

Comment: Yes of course I did it, however on the keycloak pod there is no error message, and within the postgresql pod there is nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my mistakes. It was the environments variables I wrote. Based on the [keycloak official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db), I rewrote my keycloak pod file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.6
          args: ["start"]
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: xxxx
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: xxxx
            - name: KC_DB
              value: "postgres"
            - name: KC_DB_URL_HOST
              value: "postgres-service"
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              value: "keycloak"
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              value: "your_password"
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              value: env-xxxxxxx.jcloud.ik-server.com
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "edge"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
```